# Markov chains with a stationary distribution but no limiting distribution

Tags: markov-process

I am trying to intuitively reconcile the following statement, read from "Probability, Markov Chains, and Queues":

```
A Markov Chain may possess a stationary distribution but not a limiting distribution.
```

This is unintuitive to me. I have written down 4 defenitions/facts that I know that I am trying to use:

1) $\pi$ is a limiting distribution of a Markov Chain with transition matrix $P$ if, for some initial distribution $P(0)$, $\pi = P(0)lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P^{(n)}$. The elements of $\pi$ *need not sum to 1*.

2) If, for all valid starting distributions $P(0)$, $P(0)lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P^{(n)} = \pi$, where $\pi$ is a vector of positive reals summing to 1, then $\pi$ is a *steady-state distribution*.

3) If a Markov Chain has a *steady-state distribution*, then it is also the unique *stationary distribution*.

4) A *stationary distribution* is a vector $\pi$ of positive reals summing to 1  satisfying $\pi = \pi P$.

So the original statement in question is that there is some vector $\pi$ satisfying (4) for some Markov Chains, but not 1. But fact 2 means that steady state distributions are a subset of limiting distributions, and fact 3 means that steady state distributions are stationary distributions, so how can you have a stationary distribution but not a limiting distribution? Where is my logic wrong?

EDIT: after thinking more, if the statement is correct, the chain has some $\pi = \pi P$ (4) but it is NOT true that the same $\pi$ satisfies $\pi = \pi lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P^{(n)}$, or else $\pi$ would also be a limiting distribution. I guess this means this chain has some kind of fluctuating P matrix when raised to powers. Maybe related to periodicity.

Comment: Is the definition in (1) really what you mean? (That the limit exists for *some* initial distribution?)  Take a stationary distribution $\pi$ from (4) and use this as the initial distribution for your chain.  Then $\pi = \pi P^n$, i.e. $\pi$ is automagically a "limiting distribution".

Comment: Edited my question by adding a note.

Comment: Take the equality $\pi = \pi P$.  Right multiply by $P$.  You get $\pi P  = \pi P^2$. But $\pi P  = \pi$.  Thus $\pi = \pi P^2$.  Repeating gives $\pi = \pi P^n$, for any $n \ge 1$.  Take the limit $n\to\infty$ in both sides...

Comment: Are you claiming the statement is false?

Comment: Yes, with your definitions.  I agree with @Brian Borchers below.

Answer (score 8):

The usual definition of limiting distribution is that a Markov chain has a limiting distribution $\pi$ if *for every* initial distribution $P(0)$,

$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(0)P^{(n)}=\pi
$

It's important to get that quantifier right.

A useful example to consider is the Markov chain with

$
P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right].
$

Here, $\pi=[1/2 \;\;1/2]$ is a stationary distribution but not a limiting distribution of the Markov chain.  In fact this Markov chain does not have a limiting distribution.

Comment: Brian, so then the only difference between a "limiting distribution" and a "steady state distribution" is that steady state must be a valid probability distribution whereas limiting need not sum to 1?

Comment: In my experience, "limiting distribution" and "steady state distribution" are synonyms, and both assume that $\pi$ sums to 1.

Comment: The book I mention above gives several examples of limiting distributions that do not sum to 1.